# Modifying HTML response in node-http-proxy using harmon - no output maniputlation

Tags: html, node.js, proxy

Probably a n00b question :-). I'm looking at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to create a filtering proxy. Looking for the string manipulation example I found [the pointer to harmon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596942/using-node-js-to-proxy-http-and-modify-response) and ran their [example](https://github.com/No9/harmon/blob/master/examples/simple.js) successfully.

Then I tried running my own example against an Apache HTTP listening on localhost:80. Here is my code:

```
    var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

    // Create an array of selects that harmon will process. 
    var actions = [];

    var simpleaction = {};
    simpleaction.query = 'head';
    simpleaction.func = function (node) {
                             var out = '<style type="text/css"> h1 {color : red; border-bottom : 5px solid green} </style>';
                            node.createWriteStream({ outer: true }).end(out);
                            console.log("head function called:" + out);
                            };
    var simpleaction2 = { 'query' : 'body',
                         'func' : function (node) {
                             var out = '<h1>You have been proxied</h1>';
                            node.createWriteStream({ outer: false }).end(out);
                            console.log("body function called" + out);
                            }
                        };                  

    // Add the action to the action array
    actions.push(simpleaction);
    actions.push(simpleaction2);

    var proxy = httpProxy.createServer(
      require('harmon')([], actions),
      80, 'localhost'
    );

    proxy.listen(8899);

    console.log("Up and running on port 8899");
```

Initially I got an error since I was using a newer version of http-proxy. Using 0.8.7 fixed that. The console output when loading a page now is:

```
stw@devmachine:~/tests$ nodejs ptest.js 
Up and running on port 8899
head function called:<style type="text/css"> h1 {color : red; border-bottom : 5px solid green} </style>
body function called<h1>You have been proxied
head function called:<style type="text/css"> h1 {color : red; border-bottom : 5px solid green} </style>
body function called<h1>You have been proxied
head function called:<style type="text/css"> h1 {color : red; border-bottom : 5px solid green} </style>
body function called<h1>You have been proxied
head function called:<style type="text/css"> h1 {color : red; border-bottom : 5px solid green} </style>
body function called<h1>You have been proxied</h1>
```

So it looks good, but the output isn't changed at all.
What did I miss out?

Ultimately I need to:

- add a stylesheet to the `<head>` section
- replace all `src` and `href` attributes
- add some DOM elements at specific places (e.g. a `<h1>` as first element of the body)
- add some headers
- GZIP the result before sending out
- work on http and https URLs
- leave images resources alone

Pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems strange 
Not having the full environment for your test means I can't give a definitive answer. 
But I have put together a POC here that has two actions similar to the ones you are creating.

https://gist.github.com/No9/10874082

That works fine if you clone harmon from git and drop it into the test folder.

`$ git clone https://github.com/No9/harmon.git
$ cd harmon/test 
$ curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/No9/10874082/raw/38a26d15b7ecbd875eee0988c94af0333927b98a/host-multiaction.js > host-multiaction.js
$ node host-multiaction.js`

For the overall functionality with GZIP etc I would say the new version of node-proxy would be better positioned to provide a complete solution.

I suggest watching https://github.com/No9/harmon/issues/8 for the next couple of weeks ;)

Comment: I Saw that in your content you were querying classes like ".b", while I queried elements like "a" or "body". Also I'm going after a real website. I copied my file into the test folder and found it also doesn't honour the request headers and shows the wrong site. Have a look: https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/10896955 (You should be able to run that from your test folder - compare to the direct URL http://www.notessensei.com/

Comment: So when I run your sample against www.venshare.com it works fine so it's only the request headers that need honouring now. Created this issue https://github.com/No9/harmon/issues/9 to track it as I am going to deal with the upgrade to http-proxy 1.x first

Comment: Interesting, works here too. May I make a wild guess: Venshare is 79 lines of HTML result. The other website is about 300 lines (and if you  look at the real notessensei, it is about 1000 lines -> could be the chunking? Also for my understanding: my sample seems to replace the respective node - I just want to add a child.