# Nodejs - BrowserSync running on express server

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, reverse-proxy, browser-sync

I want to pull a URL from the DB and use it as the proxied URL. However the setup I've come up with initializes a new BrowserSync server for each URL, using incrementing port numbers.

Is there a way to accomplish this without initializing a new BrowserSync server every time?

Or should I be using another approach?

```
var bs      = require("browser-sync");
var express = require("express");

var router  = express.Router();
var app     = express();

router.get("/", function(req, res){

    var proxyUrl = getUrl() //get url from db (www.example.com)

    bs.create("bs1").init({
        notify: false,
        open: false,
        ui: false,
        port: 10000,
        proxy: proxyUrl
    });
        res.send();
});

app.use(router);

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

The above is fine(ish) but is it good practice to be initializing a new server for every URL (potentially thousands)?

And is it safe to be exposing a new port number to every user of the system? (Can I mask this with a subdomain?)

#### Update

My end goal is to use a unique subdomain to refer to each proxy url.

For example:

sub1.mysite.com proxies www.example.com,

sub2.mysite.com proxies www.example2.com

Comment: This solution may work for you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075577/proxy-request-in-node-js-express

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD thanks for the help, but unfortunately it didn't help. I've edited the question. Have another look.

Comment: oh..sorry looks I missed your requirement.. Are you looking for providing proxy service for public..  Or you are trying to build SAAS application?

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD I'm trying to build a SAAS prototype. I'm choosing to use browser-sync because its the most complete reverse proxy I've seen, it has perfectly proxied every site for me so far. It also has some useful additional features.

Comment: As per me If you want SAAS service using proxy is not the good idea to go is what am thinking.. if you are going with proxy for each client will create process with new port... 

My Solution is to create node server with listen localhost and map *.domain.com to the server.. 

If you are using individual database for each client :- 
in node logic get cname from request host and use that reference to connect database.

In future if you get more clients you can implement node cluster or standard Ubuntu cluster using webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser-sync will not work as the proxy is tie to server setup.

I use following packages:

- express
- express-http-proxy
- vhost (express vhost)

```
const port = 8080;

var app = require('express')();
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var url = require('url');
var vhost = require('vhost');

app.listen(port);

/* Assuming getUrl() will return an array of sites */
// var sites = getUrl();

// DO NOT put '/' at the end of site
var sites = [
    'http://www.bing.com',
    'http://samanthagooden.com',
    'http://www.courtleigh.com'
];

var i = 0;
sites.forEach(site => {
    i++;
    var subDomain = 'sub' + i + '.mysite.com';
    app.use(vhost(subDomain, proxy(site, {
        forwardPath: (req, res) => url.parse(req.url).path,
        intercept: (rsp, data, req, res, callback) => {
            if (res._headers['content-type']) {
                var contentType = res._headers['content-type'];
                if (
                    contentType.indexOf('text') !== -1 ||
                    contentType.indexOf('javascript') !== -1
                ) {
                    // Replace link if content-type = text or javascript
                    var reg = new RegExp(site, 'g');
                    res.send(data.toString().replace(reg, ''));
                } else {
                    res.send(data);
                }
            } else {
                res.send(data);
            }
        }
    })));
    console.log(subDomain + ':' + port + ' proxy: ' + site);
});
```

The above example will create following proxies:

```
sub1.mysite.com:8080 proxy: www.bing.com
sub2.mysite.com:8080 proxy: www.example.com
```

Comment: The problem I have with express-http-proxy is that I cant seem to get around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem. Browsersync already handles all of that nicely. Any idea how to avoid this problem? A site like www.courtleigh.com is missing fonts when proxied.

Comment: @Orane Are you referring to fonts.googleapi.com 404 error? That site has the same issue even load directly.

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin is the Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) problem. You can add following piece of code to your express server app to solve it.

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
   next();
}

Comment: @JohnSiu no, not the google fonts. most notably is the social media icon fonts in the top right do not load when proxied. I've also seen the same issue on http://samanthagooden.com and a few others. Fonts failed to load.

Comment: @Orane How can I check that? Because network monitor in the browser only show 2 404 error.

Comment: @JohnSiu Ok try to proxy http://samanthagooden.com using express-http-proxy , you will see an ACAO error, however if you proxy the site using browser-sync, there will be no ACAO error. Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: @Orane I checked the proxy code of browser-sync. It is using http-proxy as the backend, but at the same time it does a lot of extra steps, including link rewrite of the site response. I don't see an easy way to use those code directly.

Comment: @JohnSiu This is insightful. I was hoping to use the existing browsersync implementation rather than figuring out the link rewrites, forwarding rules, search & replace etc. from scratch. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Orane The browser-sync proxy code is located in https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/tree/master/lib/server . Check out proxy-server.js and proxy-utils.js. The re-write code is in proxy-utils.js .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123461/discussion-between-orane-and-john-siu).

Comment: @Orane Updated code to rewrite hardcoded links in html, js, css files. Fixed fonts issue in the 2 sites given.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but Browsersync and express seems a bit overkill in this case, why not just use node-http-proxy with the native http module?

```
var http = require('http')
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

var options = ...
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options)

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var proxyUrl = getUrl()
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: proxyUrl })
})

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:8080')
})
```

Comment: The problem I have with node-http-proxy is that I cant seem to get around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem. Browsersync already handles all of that nicely and I have plans to use "ghost mode" in the future.

Comment: Any idea how to avoid this problem? A site like www.courtleigh.com is missing fonts when proxied.

Comment: The only way to get around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin safely is to ensure that all requests after the HTML are also made to your proxy and not the real address. This means your proxy must inspect the webpage and replace every reference to the real site to your proxy. In www.courtleigh.com, several absolute references to their website is used in the source, all these must be search&replaced to your proxy.

Comment: You are right! The browsersync library has already taken care of the extra steps necessary to search&replace, forwarding rules, etc. This is the main reason why I was hoping to use the browsersync library instead of trying to figure out the details of their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As per me If you want SAAS service using proxy is not the good idea to go is what am thinking.. if you are going with proxy for each client will create process with new port... My Solution is to create node server with listen localhost and map *.domain.com to the server..

If you are using individual database for each client :- 
in node logic get cname from request host and use that reference to connect database.

Final Controller code would be..
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        var client = req.subdomains[0];
        console.log(client);
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/'+client, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  db.collection('app1').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
        console.log('data');
    console.log(result);
  });
});

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
~                                                                                                                                              
~
```

In future if you get more clients you can implement node cluster or standard Ubuntu cluster using webservice