# Nodejs - Disable or destroy vhost subdomains/proxies

Tags: node.js, proxy, express-vhost

I have the follow code which dynamically proxies a website to a subdomain.

```
var app = require('express')();
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var vhost = require('vhost');

app.get('/make', function (req, res) {
    app.use(vhost('sub1.mysite.com', proxy("www.example.com");
    res.send("Proxy Created");
});

app.get('/destroy', function (req, res) {

    // Disable or Destroy the subdomain/proxy created above
    // ???

});
app.listen(8080);
```

How would I disable or destroy this newly created proxy/subdomain from the `/destroy` route?

Comment: Updated answer to create the vhost router inside DomainProxy.js. The app code is cleaner now.

Comment: Updated `dp.create()` to take array argument.

Comment: @JohnSiu nice!! Would you say this is a solid way to recreate 1000+ proxies if the app crashes?

Comment: Yes, as long as the array list is recreated/reload after restart, there is no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app.js**

```
var Ex = require('express');
var app = Ex();
app.listen(8080);

var DomainProxy = require('./DomainProxy').DomainProxy;
// Pass express instance 'app' into dp,
// dp will create a vhost router internally
var dp = new DomainProxy(app);

var proxies = [
    { domain: '1.local', site: 'http://www.bing.com' },
    { domain: '2.local', site: 'http://samanthagooden.com' },
    { domain: '3.local', site: 'http://www.courtleigh.com' },
    { domain: '4.local', site: 'http://example.com' }
];

dp.create(proxies);

app.get('/make', function (req, res) {
    var subDomain = 'sub1.mysite.com';
    var site = 'http://www.example.com'; // site need to contain 'http://', else dp link rewrite will not work correctly

    dp.create([{domain:subDomain,site:site}]);

    res.send("Proxy Created");
});

app.get('/destroy', function (req, res) {

    var subDomain = 'sub1.mysite.com';

    dp.destroy(subDomain);

    res.send("Proxy Destroyed");

});
```

**DomainProxy.js**

I also incorporated my answer from [Nodejs - BrowserSync running on express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072317/nodejs-browsersync-running-on-express-server)

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var url = require('url');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var Ex = require('express');

var DomainProxy = (function () {
    function DomainProxy(app) { // DomainProxy
        this.list = []; // vhost list array
        this.router = Ex.Router();
        app.use(this.router);
    }
    DomainProxy.prototype.create = function (proxies) {

        proxies.forEach(p => {

            // Destroy old proxy first
            this.destroy(p.domain);

            this.list.push(p.domain); // Add domain into list

            this.router.use(vhost(p.domain, proxy(p.site, {
                forwarDomainProxyath: (req, res) => url.parse(req.url).path,
                intercept: (rsp, data, req, res, callback) => {
                    if (res._headers['content-type']) {
                        var contentType = res._headers['content-type'];
                        // console.log(contentType);
                        if (
                            contentType.indexOf('text') !== -1 ||
                            contentType.indexOf('javascript') !== -1
                        ) {
                            // Rewrite links
                            var reg = new RegExp(p.site, 'g');
                            res.send(data.toString().replace(reg, ''));
                        } else {
                            res.send(data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        res.send(data);
                    }
                }
            })));
        })
    };
    DomainProxy.prototype.destroy = function (domain) {
        var i = this.list.indexOf(domain);
        if (i !== -1) {
            this.list.splice(i, 1);
            this.router.stack.splice(i, 1);
        }
    };
    return DomainProxy;
} ());
exports.DomainProxy = DomainProxy;
```